# Assign results of rowSums to a new column in R

Tags: r, rowsum

I have the below dataframe which contains number of products sold in each quarter by a salesman.

```
Ag      Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
s121    4   3   0   0
S431    0   0   2   1   
S246    0   0   0   2
S444    2   2   2   2
```

I am trying to create a calculated column C which is basically sum of all columns where the value is not zero. So basically number of quarters a salesman has been active.

Expected output:

```
Ag      Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4 C
s121    4   3   0   0   2
S431    0   0   2   1   2
S246    0   0   0   2   1
S444    2   2   2   2   4
```

I have tried

```
df$C <- df[rowSums(df[,c(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)])]
```

but this gives undefined columns selected error.
Can someone please help me rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply this way:

```
dat$C <- rowSums(dat[, -1] != 0)
dat

#     Ag Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 C
# 1 s121  4  3  0  0 2
# 2 S431  0  0  2  1 2
# 3 S246  0  0  0  2 1
# 4 S444  2  2  2  2 4
```

Data:

```
dat <- structure(
  list(
    Ag = c("s121", "S431", "S246", "S444"),
    Q1 = c(4L,
           0L, 0L, 2L),
    Q2 = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 2L),
    Q3 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 2L),
    Q4 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 2L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-4L)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply()`, and what you want is the `length()`s.

```
dat <- transform(dat, C=apply(dat[-1], 1, function(x) length(x[x != 0])))
dat
#     Ag Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 C
# 1 s121  4  3  0  0 2
# 2 S431  0  0  2  1 2
# 3 S246  0  0  0  2 1
# 4 S444  2  2  2  2 4
```

You could also do this with `rowSums()` when you convert to `"logical"`.

```
transform(dat, C=rowSums(as.data.frame(lapply(dat[-1], as.logical))))
#     Ag Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 C
# 1 s121  4  3  0  0 2
# 2 S431  0  0  2  1 2
# 3 S246  0  0  0  2 1
# 4 S444  2  2  2  2 4
```

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(Ag = c("s121", "S431", "S246", "S444"), Q1 = c(4L, 
0L, 0L, 2L), Q2 = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 2L), Q3 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 2L), 
    Q4 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably @utubun's approach is the most simplest but here are few more base R options.

```
df$C <-  apply(df[-1] != 0, 1, sum)
df
#    Ag Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 C
#1 s121  4  3  0  0 2
#2 S431  0  0  2  1 2
#3 S246  0  0  0  2 1
#4 S444  2  2  2  2 4
```

Or with `Reduce` and `lapply`

```
df$C <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(df[-1], function(x) x != 0))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Ag = c("s121", "S431", "S246", "S444"), Q1 = c(4L, 
0L, 0L, 2L), Q2 = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 2L), Q3 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 2L), 
Q4 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```